# PDF Accessibility | 'Title - Failed' Error in Acrobat Pro while generating PDF using XSL-FO

Tags: xsl-fo

I am generating a PDF document from an XML using XSL template in Apache FOP API. My applications requires the PDF documents to be generated dynamically.

Despite of adding the title (code snippet below), I am getting 'Title - Failed' error when checked for Accessibility (full check) in Adobe Acrobat Pro 11.

```
<fo:declarations>
            <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/">
                <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
                    <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
      xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
                        <!-- Dublin Core properties go here -->
                        <dc:title>Document title</dc:title>
                        <dc:creator>Document author</dc:creator>
                        <dc:description>Document subject</dc:description>
                    </rdf:Description>
                    <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
      xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/">
                        <!-- XMP properties go here -->
                        <xmp:CreatorTool>Tool used to make the PDF</xmp:CreatorTool>
                    </rdf:Description>
                </rdf:RDF>
            </x:xmpmeta>
        </fo:declarations>
```

Comment: Which FOP version are you using?  Is your `fo:declarations` between your `fo:layout-master-set` and the first `fo:page-sequence`?

Comment: FOP version 1.1 & yes, I am putting the declaration between the tag blocks mentioned by you.

Comment: I'm out of ideas, since the only information that I have is http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1/metadata.html, and you seem to be working from that, too.

Comment: Now I am using FOP 2.0, but still no luck with Title-Failing error. :-(

Answer (score 1):

In Adobe Acrobat If I go to File --> Properties --> Initial View --> Select 'Document Title' in Show, the error is fixed. But I am not able to find anything to do the same thing programmatically, neither in XSL template nor in java code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this issue has been fixed, probably in version 2.1.  I just upgraded to FOP 2.2 after having this same issue while using version 1.1, and I'm pleased to report that everything works as expected now after opening a dynamically-generated PDF-UA file with Adobe Acrobat XI Pro.